# Unable to order by a sub_query result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up a Datatable table using serverside processing but I can't make my order by statement work.

The returned table shows a list of courses and then the registration count for different registration statuses. Example:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  town, 
  start_date, 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) 
   FROM registration r 
   WHERE r.course = c.id AND r.status = 'REG') as reg_count, 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) 
   FROM registration r 
   WHERE r.course = c.id AND r.status = 'CAN') as can_count 
FROM courses c
```

When I want to order by reg_count I can't just add ORDER BY reg_count and if I try and add the ORDER BY inside the sub_query it returns a random order. I'm sure it's possible but can't quite figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: "*I can't just add ORDER BY reg_count*" why do you think that? Citing from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html): "*An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column*". But inside the subquery, of course what sense would an `ORDER BY` make? Each of the subqueries returns only one row ...

Comment: If I do add it in the ORDER BY I get Unknown column 'reg_count' in 'order clause'?

Comment: Seems to work fine in this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wMmwZsCoFt4oXt5DBasy2f/0 How exactly does your query look like when you add the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Thanks. I've just run my full query, with the ORDER BY clause in PHPMyAdmin and you're right it is working, so there must be something inside my MYSQL library that's causing the error as it's the same MYSQL query being called on my site that I used in PHPMyAdmin. Thanks, I'll do a bit more digging.

Comment: Found the problem. My MySQL class is set up to run a 'count statement' along with each query, to return the row count. The order by clause was being passed on to this query but the column doesn't exist as it's a simple count(*) for the field list! Thanks for the help.

Comment: So delete the question, it is of no use to others

Comment: I can't delete as 'others have invested time and effort into answering it'

Answer (score 0):

You could try a left join like this:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  town, 
  start_date ,
  total_reg.reg_count,
  total_can.can_count
FROM 
  courses c
LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(id) as reg_count , course FROM registration WHERE status = 'REG' GROUP BY course) as total_reg ON total_reg.course = c.course 
LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(id) as reg_count , course FROM registration WHERE status = 'CAN' GROUP BY course) as total_reg ON total_reg.course = c.course
ORDER BY total_reg.reg_count;
```

You may require to modify GROUP by column according to your result.

Answer (score -1):

The problem wasn't with the query but with my MySQL class I use, which was calling another query and adding the order by clause to it when it's not required.

Comment: "*but with my MySQL class I use, which ..."* that's often a problem with such custom wrappers: They do something to the queries passed in, that may not be applicable for all queries. And when something doesn't work as expected, everybody totally "forgets" about that wrapper, begins bughunting in a perfectly valid query and can't understand why a query doesn't work.

Comment: I personally for such handcrafted queries exectue them always directly in some simple database client (for instance phpMyAdmin) before including them in my application. So I can be sure, the query per se works. And if something goes wrong, it's the code that is executing the query and not the query itself ...